# how to find this function $f(x)$ satisfying these conditions?

Tags: functions, derivatives, exponential-function

How to find a function $f(x)$ that satisfies:

1. $f(x)$ defines only on the positive axis of X;
2. when $x\to 0$, $f(x)\to +\infty$.
3. Exist a positive real number $k$, when $x\to k$, $f(x)\to 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x>k$.
4. $f'(x)<0$ for $x\in[0,k)$, and $f'(k)=0$.
5. $f''(x)>0$.

Thanks.

Comment: The fifth point should be for $0<x<k$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f:\mathbb{R_+} \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\cot^2(x) & 0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
0 & x\geq \dfrac{\pi}{2}.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are so many examples so that it is difficult to chose. One example is
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+\frac{1}{x}-2 & 0<x<1\\
0 & x\geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Here $k=1$ of course.